# Why does IE sometimes return multiple "MSIE X.0" versions in the User Agent field?

Tags: browser

We're running into a User Agent that I've never seen before. Since we're trying to reproduce a problem this user is experiencing, I'd like to mirror his setup as much as possible, but am stumped as to what this User Agent string implies:

> Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 8.0**; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0;
>   Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; **MSIE 6.0**; Windows NT 5.1; SV1) ; .NET CLR
>   1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; AskTbX-SD/5.12.2.16749)

Can anyone explain how/why IE would be reporting both MSIE 8.0 and MSIE 6.0 in the same user agent string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s probably caused by some buggy add-on. All things after „Trident” are added by add-ons.